# SVG search engine

Tags: web-apps, search-engine, vector-graphics, svg, hosted

I am looking for a search engine that efficiently finds vector images (so SVG, mostly).

- I should not show results for other formats such as web pages or PDF
- Available online, free to use
- It must be a real crawler, not just a repository of SVG files such as https://openclipart.org/
- Bonus if it shows license information for each file

---

Google can't do this:

[image: Google Search: select list of file type, including '.rtf' and '.swf', but not '.svg']

Comment: Do you want to host that software yourself – or are you [looking for a website](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/191/185)? ;)

Comment: @Izzy: Looking for a webapp, not hosted myself. This strikes me as a question that would perform well here, as it asks for a very specific tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Google ***can*** [search for SVG files](http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/google-image-search-indexes-svg-files.html). [Lifehacker agrees](http://lifehacker.com/5759730/see-only-resize-friendly-scalable-vector-graphics-svg-in-google-image-search).

> January 28, 2011
>
> Google Image Search Indexes SVG Files Last year,
>   Google announced that it started to index SVG files, but the results
>   were only returned by the web search engine. "SVG is an open,
>   XML-based format for vector graphics with support for interactive
>   elements. We're big fans of open standards, and our mission is to
>   organize the world's information, so indexing SVG is a natural step.
>   We index SVG content whether it is in a standalone file or embedded
>   directly in HTML," explained Google at that time.
>
> Now you can find SVG files in Google Image Search by restricting the
>   results to this filetype in the advanced search page or by using the
>   filetype operator. Here's an example: [[molecule filetype:svg]](https://www.google.com/images?as_q=molecule&hl=en&tbs=isch:1,ift:svg). If you
>   restrict the results to Wikipedia, Google returns 57,300 SVG files.

[image]

Comment: short answer: add `filetype:svg` to your query